# Getting System.Type instance from string Type.GetType(string) with Type.AssemblyQualifiedName and Type.FullName

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp, .net-native

My server (IIS, ASP.NET) receives requests from clients based on different platforms (UWP, Windows Phone 8.1, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS) and those clients process responses from my server.

When I process a request on my server or a response on client I deal with the following data:

1. Value type info - obtained from someValue.GetType().[AssemblyQualifiedName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Value itself in a serialized form (byte array).

In order to deserialize data I used to do the following:

```
Type valueType = Type.GetType(iValue.assemblyQualifiedName, true);
object value = <deserializing value using its valueType>
```

This worked fine both at server and client sides until I began dealing with the **UWP** clients compiled with the **.NET native tool chain**.

The problem is that basic types like **System.String** used to reside in **mscorlib** assembly but on the new UWP clients `stringValue.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName` returns something like

> System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

which leads to the following exception on my server:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

at `Type.GetType(iValue.assemblyQualifiedName, true)`.

If I got that right, I can use the [Type.GetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) method with [Type.FullName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [Type.AssemblyQualifiedName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx) for types defined in the **Mscorlib** assembly.

But my code is unified between all the clients and server (PCL). What if a type is defined in the **System.Private.CoreLib** assembly on UWP client? How do I better deal with this problem?

Comment: @code4life How does Activator help me getting the Type instance by its ID?

Comment: did you try "stringValue.GetType().FullName"?

Comment: @anion ATM I am building a prototype to check if `Type.GetType(stringValue.GetType().FullName, true)` would work at UWP client compiled with .NET native. The thing I fear of is that some types defined in mscorlib will work and some other will not. Uncomfortable feeling of incompatibility. I will update my question when I have results.

Comment: @ZverevEugene:  `Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @code4life It has nothing to do with my question. Give yourself an effort to read it.

Comment: You're surely too late to discover this and do something decent about it, having a bunch of clients out there already.  All that's left that's practical is translating assembly names.  Next time pick something more portable, like XML, Json or Protobufs.

Comment: @HansPassant I am using all those (XML via DataContractSerializer, Json via Newtonsoft and Protobuf via Protobuf-net). DataContractSerializer by Microsoft is useless because it's xamain (i.e. mono) implementation is not compatible between xamarin.android and windows. Json (Newtonsoft) cannot handle dictionaries with complex keys which I use much. I ended up using protobuf at the moment but even then I need to know the root object Type. This knowledge is what my question is about :) BTW I solved my problem and will post my solution in the nearest future.

Comment: @HansPassant I forgot to mention that my solution is a kind of translation of assembly names. I am glad my thought came the same way as yours :) The trick was to make a translation which does not require maintaining the translation metadata by hand. I hope the logic I made up will do the trick. Testing it atm. Anyway, thank you for the hint.